# How to resolve android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table error?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, insert

I've been building a doctor's app on Android Studio, and using the SQLite database to store data. In it, there is an activity in which the doctor can manage his appointments. This is how the interface looks like.
[image: The Manage Appointments Activity]

So I've been working with the coding to get the input from the user, and store it in SQLite database. There are two tables in my database for now. One has the login details, the other is supposed to have the appointments details. This is my DBHelper class.

```
    package com.example.doctorsapp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,"Login.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase myDB) {
        myDB.execSQL("create Table users(username Text primary key, password Text)");
        myDB.execSQL("create Table appointments(patientName Text, patientAge Text, appointmentDate Text, Time Text, Number Text)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase myDB, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        myDB.execSQL("drop Table if exists users");
        myDB.execSQL("drop Table if exists appointments");

    }
```

This is the method which will add data to the database

```
    public Boolean insertappointment(String patientName, String patientAge, String appointmentDate, String Time, String Number)
{
    SQLiteDatabase myDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("patientName", patientName);
    contentValues.put("patientAge", patientAge);
    contentValues.put("appointmentDate", appointmentDate);
    contentValues.put("Time", Time);
    contentValues.put("Number", Number);
    long appmntRes = myDB.insert("appointments", null,contentValues);
    if(appmntRes == -1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is the ManageAppointments class

```
    package com.example.doctorsapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class ManageAppointments extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText patientName, patientAge,appointmentDate, Time, Number;
    Button btnAddAppointment, btnUpdateAppointment, btnDeleteAppointment, btnViewAppointment;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    DBHelper myDB;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage_appointments);

        patientName = findViewById(R.id.patientName);
        patientAge = findViewById(R.id.patientAge);
        appointmentDate = findViewById(R.id.appointmentDate);
        Time = findViewById(R.id.Time);
        Number = findViewById(R.id.Number);
        btnAddAppointment = findViewById(R.id.btnAddAppointment);
        btnUpdateAppointment = findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateAppointment);
        btnDeleteAppointment = findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteAppointment);
        btnViewAppointment = findViewById(R.id.btnViewAppointment);


        btnAddAppointment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myDB = new DBHelper(ManageAppointments.this);
               Boolean check = myDB.insertappointment(patientName.getText().toString().trim(), patientAge.getText().toString().trim(),
                       appointmentDate.getText().toString().trim(),Time.getText().toString().trim(),Number.getText().toString().trim());
                if(check == true)
                    Toast.makeText(ManageAppointments.this, "Appointment Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(ManageAppointments.this, "Appointment Not Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

However when I run the emulator, and insert data, I get the toast message "Appointment Not Added". I was debugging and it seems the problem is the values are not getting inserted in to the database. The appmntRes which is in the insert method of my DBHelper class, is returning -1, which means data insertion has failed. Why is that happening? Is something wrong with the way I have created my second table? Would really appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance!!

Edit: I just checked the logcat while running my app and I got the message `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: appointments`

Why is my second table not being created? Please help.

Comment: I tested here and is working just fine, i'll give you some tips, when I'm updating the database i usually, uninstall the app and install again, there is a guide that helps to check queries. take a look at here: https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing your code, i believe that you need to close the database after the operation, and that the data is being saved but you aren't getting the right response.So here are the changes that i think need to be made.

change:

```
Boolean check;
check.booleanValue();
```

to

```
boolean check
```

and in your database you need to close after using, so in the method insertappointment() use in the end of the operation:

```
myDB.close;
```

in this way the connection to the database is closed

Comment: Nope, it didn't work :( they threw errors